# How to Browse all messages from Anypoint MQ using REST Calls?

Tags: java, rest, message-queue, mq, mulesoft

I am trying to browse all queued messages(without removing) in Anypoint MQ. 
Assume queue contains 50 messages.

https://mq-.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations//environments//destinations//messages?pollingTime=10000&batchSize=10&lockTtl=120000

1) But it is retrieving only few messages. How can I get all queue messages using the above endpoint?
2) Is it possible to mention polling time max and wait until reading all queue messages at least a specified batch size?

Comment: Are you using FIFO queue ? would you be able to provide some details around you requirement. Is it a batch based scenario or a near real time scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

As I saw that your request is correct.

Using the Anypoint MQ Broker API, you can batch-upload and batch-retrieve messages from a standard or FIFO queue. For information, see Anypoint MQ Broker API.

https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/anypoint-mq-broker/minor/1.0/console/method/%23444/

**You can upload or retrieve a maximum of 10 messages (default) in a single call.**

For batch-retrieve operations, use the batchSize query parameter to specify the number of messages to retrieve. Anypoint MQ Broker API doesn’t guarantee the number of messages retrieved in a single call.

Answer (score 0):

@kumar - it doesn't work in that way. you can retrieve at max 10 messages in a single call to broker api with locktime.
you can find more details on this page-
https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/anypoint-mq-broker/minor/1.0/console/method/%23395/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30377425)